# How to interactive process in shell on influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am a beginner with InfluxDB. When I use shell "EOF" to access influxdb, but it thow out an error `error parsing query: found use, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1`.

Here is the script as follows

```
influx << EOF
use testdb
insert test,altitude=1000,area=北 temperature=11,humidity=-4
EOF
```

Did not influx support interactive processing in shell?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `USE` or `INSERT` when piping into influx. These commands (and [others](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/tools/shell/#influx-commands)) are specific to the interactive command line and disabled when stdin is not a tty.

You need to save data to a text file and use `-import` option:

```
influx -host=localhost -port=8086 -import -path data.txt
```

where data.txt should look like this:

```
# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: testdb
test,altitude=1000,area=北 temperature=11,humidity=-4
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/tools/shell/#import-data-from-a-file-with-import) for details.

---

Alternatively, you can [directly use the HTTP API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/guides/writing_data/#writing-points-from-a-file) via curl:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=testdb" --data-binary @- << EOF
test,altitude=1000,area=北 temperature=11,humidity=-4
EOF
```

Comment: Can i know why we need to comment  these lines in the text file ``` # DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: testdb```

Comment: @SG131712 These header lines are specified to start with #. Actually, influx expects the header lines to be formatted exactly like the sample including the spacing: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/v1.8.1/importer/v8/importer.go#L181

Comment: With DDL i executed the command and i could see below result  `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-10 bin]$ ./influx -import -path=/home/ec2-user/data/import.txt -precision=ns
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Processed 1 commands
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Processed 3 inserts
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Failed 0 inserts`

Comment: which means data is inserted but when i checked in database nothing is displaying `> use import
Using database import
> precision rfc3339
> select * from import limit 3
>
`